# Google Analytics not pulling in the title of a Service Cloud Knowledge Article

Tags: community, customer-community, knowledge, google-analytics

In the data from SFDC to GA, instead of the data from the title field, SFDC is sending the words "Article Detail" for every single knowledge base article. Is this able to be changed? Is anyone else experiencing this?

other fields' data is coming through as expected like "dimension", "location", "page"

Answer (score 0):

I am seeing this problem as well.  It is not happening all the time for me.  See the link I just posted about this (below).  Did you find an explanation or solution?

[Google Analytics - Salesforce Community](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/273476/google-analytics-salesforce-community)

Comment: Nope! Never figured it out. Thank you for linking me to your question as well.